# Google oAuth2: How do I get ALL my email addresses from my google account on android?

Tags: android, email, google-oauth

I'm working on an android app which uses Google accounts for authorization as described on [android's developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html%29).
The login part and fetching oauth2 token works fine. But for some reason I can only request my primary email address.

For the communication with other users I want to fetch all my email addresses which can be used to login to my selected Google account.

For example:

- I created a Google account with my private mail address `"xy@mail.com"`.
- As a result I got `"xy@googlemail.com"` and "xy@gmail.com".

So User B knows me as `“xy@mail.com”` and User C knows me as `“xy@gmail.com”` but both should address me logged in as `“xy@googlemail.com”`.

I tried different scopes…

- h**ps://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- h**ps://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- h**ps://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
- h**ps://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

…and different approaches (URL, Plus libs).

I know that the Google id could be an alternative but I would prefer to avoid requesting the Google id for every single contact if this is possible at all.

Thanks in advance.